# How to get Assemblies Generated at Runtime to use Project Dependencies? C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, dynamically-generated

Is it possible to allow dynamically generated assemblies to access dependencies that exist in the project that generates the new assembly? I am working with Unity and C#, and I add an assembly that contains dependencies that exist in the project it now belongs to, but I get this error: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ModAssembly000.dll' or one of its dependencies . I get this error because I try to put 'using UnityEngine' at the top of the script. This is the code that already exists in the project that gets the new assembly and invokes a method:

```
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    parameters.OutputAssembly = generatedName;
    CompilerResults r = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, filePath);
    r.CompiledAssembly.GetType("ModData").GetMethod("Run").Invoke(null, BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
```

This is the source for the dynamically created assembly:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ModData {
    public static string modName = "Super kool mod";
    public static string modVersion = "1.2.1";

    public static void Run() {
        Debug.Log("it worked :D");
    }
}
```

UnityEngine (thus, Debug.Log) exists in the code that is generating this assembly. Is there a way I can get the new created assembly to use the UnityEngine that exists above it so that I could allow the new code to do anything in the project above it? I know ModAssembly000.dll exists because if I remove the 'using UnityEngine' line, then I can access the static string filds of the dynamic assembly without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to add Unity to the list of referenced assemblies:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("UnityEngine.dll");
```

Comment: Indeed that was it. I overlooked it. Thank you for your time!